# Time Limit Exceeded for Code Written for Problem in binarysearch.com

Tags: python, function, binary-search

I have written a code for the following problem :
Given a list of numbers "nums" and a number "k", return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k. You may not use the same element twice.

Constraints: `n ≤ 100,000` where "n" is the length of "nums"
The code I wrote is  below:

```
class Solution:
def solve(self, nums, k):
    a=0
    if len(nums)<= 100000:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                if i !=j:
                    if nums[i]+nums[j]==k:
                        a =1  
        if a==1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

It is showing time limit exceeded for a test case with `nums = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1....`
What is wrong with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think your complexity is O(n^2) and you need to use hashmap concept here.
For python, make use of dictionary